# Django REST: custom styling

Tags: python, django, rest

Got attuned to work on Django project that used Django Rest Framework. Current GUI uses default styling.

I would like to re-style it.

There is an article describing re-styling:
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/browsable-api/

However I don't understand where to add `rest_framework` folder with the `api.html`. My existing project doesn't contain any folder related to REST.

*"To customize the default style, create a template called rest_framework/api.html that extends from rest_framework/base.html"*

Where to put `rest_framework`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out, that putting `rest_framework` into `/templates/` folder does the trick.

So the full path is: `/templates/rest_framework/api.html`.

Answer (score 2):

It's up to you, every template dir will overwrite the default one.

I would recommend to use

> /yourapp/yourapp/templates/rest_framework

as you probably want to use your template for the whole app.